# fontawesome icon not working correctly in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone give me an example of using font-awesome in React.js?
I have imported the react font-awesome. But the icon doesn't show on the browser. I can see the classname has been set on the dom but there is no CSS style associated with the dom.

**Steps followed by me**

1) npm install --save react-fontawesome

2) Inside my JS file :

```
   import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
   <FontAwesome name="rocket size="lg"" />
```

Comment: You might need to capitalize on the Name (e.g. <i className="fa fa-calendar"></i>).

Comment: At some top-level component (your app or page) you need to include the CSS that actually pulls in the FontAwesome font and classes. Otherwise, your class names don't mean anything. So, in your App.js (for example) you'd add something like: import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

Comment: There is no css file in react-awesome when installed via npm. For this I will need to include CDN in root file. But i don't want both react-awesome npm and CDN. It might be over head I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack with react.js what you need to do is to load the font with a **loader**, first install font-awesome and then
configure the loader in webpack.

```
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|svg|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
}
```

try it out and let me know.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that you should import font awesome CSS

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
```

then just reference like any other class like:

```
<span className="fa fa-facebook"></span>
```

Comment: I added above code to webpack. What I am getting is span.fa.fa-rocket.fa-lg in DOM with dimensions 0*30.
I guess because of dimensions it is not showing up

Comment: Jack...I don't have any css file in react-fontawesome... I had did npm install react-fontawesome ...don't know why...so while importing 
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'  i am getting module not found

Comment: try just to install font awesome, react font-awesome is an overkill 
npm install font-awesome, then follow the steps I wrote

Comment: Thank you Jack. I am going with font awesome CDN

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the easiest way is to use @fortawesome/react-fontawesome as mentioned on fontawesome website.
install the package with

```
 yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
 yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
 yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

After that simply import the pack

`import { faCog } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"`

And use it

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} />`